# Passing a function with default parameters

Tags: scala, functional-programming, default-parameters

In Scala (v2.8.0, on SimplyScala.com), if I define a 2-ary function with a default parameter, why can't I pass it as a 1-ary function?

This

```
def bah(c:Char, i:Int = 0) = i
List('a','b','c').map(bah)
```

gives this

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Char, Int) => Int
 required: (Char) => ?
       List('a','b','c').map(bah)
```

Comment: What would you expect the result of `List('a','b','c').map(bah)` to be?

Comment: I'd expect `List(0,0,0)`. More generally, I'd expect it to be equivalent to `List(bah('a'), bah('b'), bah('c'))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you defined is a **method**, not a function.

What scala do is translate `List('a','b','c').map(bah)` to `List('a','b','c').map((c: Char, i: Int) => bah(c, i))`, because `map` need a function, you can't pass a method to it.

Finally, scala found type mismatch and warn you.

A workaround:

```
List('a','b','c').map(c => bah(c))
```

**Edit:**

A further explanation, we can only pass functions as parameters not method(because function is object), and there is no way to cast a method to a function, you can only build a function calling that method. But sometimes scala can build that function for you from a method which makes you mistakenly think method can be passed as parameter.

Anyway, building function is easy in scala. And with type inference, you can omit the type of input parameter when pass it to a method like `List('a','b','c').map(c => bah(c))`, you build a function `c => bah(c)` and you don't need to point out `c` is `Char`.

Comment: What makes this a method? Removing the second parameter removes the error: `def bah(c:Char) = 0`.

Comment: But then why does removing the second parameter allow the method to be passed?

Comment: @leewangzhong like I said in the answer, scala will translate it to a function. If your method only have one parameter, then the translated function also has only one parameter which match the type `(Char) => ?`.

Comment: Is there a way to "cast" it to a function, or must I define the function manually? I think I see the problem, but I think your answer isn't really informative enough for a general Scala newbie.

Comment: Would you mind if I edit the answer later with information I think would be helpful for understanding?